# MAMP mysql issue

Tags: mysql, mamp

I am currently using MAMP and I've come across an issue when I try to access `localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English`

I get `Error: Could not connect to MySQL server!`

All of my sites are accessible, just not the MAMP admin area.
I've read that I may need to change the password, but when I run

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password NEWPASSWORD
```

I get:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

Why is any of this happening and how can I get it back to working order?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the root password is not what you expect it to be. No telling how that happened or if it's simple typos, but just in case it got changed out from under you, here is a handy little guide to resetting the root password, which will allow you to administer other users passwords, etc.

[mysql.com reset root password on Unix](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix)

Comment: How does that apply to MAMP? The directory structure is different and I can't find that pid file or how to restart mysql using a text doc.

Comment: I'm no expert, but you might find the pid using `ps auxwww | grep mysql` (if mamp is running - note the lines returned are really long - 3 for me (one is grep), and begin with your username). possibly: `kill cat /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid` (note: wrap the 'cat /file' in backticks like the article)

Comment: I agree that your password might not be what you expect.  I was trying to add a non-alphanumeric character into my password (trying to do the secure password thing).  Unfortunately, i did this using the mysqladmin command line tool under BASH.  This particular non-alphanumeric character has special meaning in BASH, and causes unexpected results when typed into a command.  So, my password ended up being a few letters I was expecting and then about 200 more characters I wasn't expecting.  Had to reinstall MAMP after that...

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to also modify /Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/index.php.  The mysql root password is hard coded in there.  You want to change this line:

```
$link = @mysql_connect(':/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock', 'root', 'root');
```

so the second "root" is what you changed your mysql root user's password to be.  Hopefully, when you launch index.php, you will no longer get that error.